# use MovieClip target name to pass variable to function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, function, mouseevent, event-listener

How can I combine the following functions and still pass a different string to the `buildUI();` function?

I have two functions that do the same thing only at the end they both call a function and pass a String value to the function. This string value is the only thing different.

Below is are my eventlisteners and functions as they are now:

```
    female_start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startFemale);
    male_start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMale);


//FUNCTIONS THAT DO THE SAME THING AND BOTH CALL  buildUI BUT PASS A DIFFERENT STRING. 
function startMale(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {

            female_start.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startFemale);
            male_start.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMale);
            var removeMale = new Tween(male_start, "x", Strong.easeInOut, 540,1080, 2, true); 
            var removeFemale = new Tween(female_start, "x", Strong.easeInOut, 0,-540, 2, true); 
//THIS IS THE ONLY DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THE TWO FUNCTIONS
            buildUI("Male");
     }


function startFemale(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

            female_start.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startFemale);
            male_start.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMale);
            var removeMale = new Tween(male_start, "x", Strong.easeInOut, 540,1080, 2, true); 
            var removeFemale = new Tween(female_start, "x", Strong.easeInOut, 0,-540, 2, true); 
//THIS IS THE ONLY DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THE TWO FUNCTIONS
            buildUI("Female");
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
female_start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(e){start(e, "female");});
male_start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(e){start(e, "male");});
function start(event:MouseEvent, sex:String):void{
  //do all the stuff
  buidUI(sex);
}
```